# SQL to generate JSON in specific format

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am using MS SQL. I have this Table:

```
SELECT id, description, contacts, type FROM Table1 WHERE id = 'AA'
```

Output:

```
id  description        contacts  type
AA  Albany Associates  12        static
AA  Albany Associates  23        static
AA  Albany Associates  13        static
AA  Albany Associates  45        static
AA  Albany Associates  23        static
AA  Albany Associates  43        static
```

Anyone please help me how should I write SQL to get an JSON output like this:

```
{"id":"AA",
"description":"Albany Associates",
"members":
    {
        "contacts":
                    ["12","23","13","45","43","23","43"]},
        "type":     "Static"
    }
```

I tried this:

```
    SELECT id, description, contacts, type FROM Table1 WHERE id = 'AA' FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

and output came like this:

```
 {"id":"AA",
"description":"Albany Associates",
"contact_1004_contactID":"12",
"type":"static"}
,{"id":"AA",
"description":"Albany Associates",
"contact_1004_contactID":"23",
"type":"static"}
```

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: If you're invoking the SQL from some programming language (for example, C#, Java or Python), then use a JSON library in that language to "pretty print".  Do your query in SQL, do everything else in your higher-level language.  Don't rely on the (MSSQL-specific) JSON queries for formatting.

Comment: I am using c#. So I can get datatable in my c# code. Do I have to build string manually by defining class, deserialize json and all sort of things ? I thought MS SQL would have some trick to do that.

Comment: Important thing I forgot to ask before I posted my answer: what should the output be if `description` or `type` varies? My current answer will simply split these into separate objects, and the result will not be a (valid) single JSON object.

Comment: They will not varies. Its the description and type of that particular id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
SELECT *
INTO Table1
FROM (VALUES
('AA','Albany Associates','12','static'),
('AA','Albany Associates','23','static'),
('AA','Albany Associates','13','static'),
('AA','Albany Associates','45','static'),
('AA','Albany Associates','23','static'),
('AA','Albany Associates','43','static')) 
T(id, description, contacts, [type])
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    description, 
    JSON_QUERY(
        (SELECT '[' +
            STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(contacts, 'json') + '"', ',') +
         ']')) AS "members.contacts",
    [type] AS "type"
FROM Table1
WHERE id = 'AA'
GROUP BY id, description, [type]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Output (pretty-printed, which SQL Server doesn't natively do):

```json
{
    "id": "AA",
    "description": "Albany Associates",
    "members": {
        "contacts": ["12", "23", "13", "45", "23", "43"]
    },
    "type": "static"
}
```

Note the clunky way in which we have to build the string array. Unfortunately T-SQL has no native function for building a JSON scalar array. Given the input we don't strictly need to include the `STRING_ESCAPE` call (since there are no special characters) but it's safer to include it anyway, in case there might be.

SQL Server 2016 doesn't have `STRING_AGG`, so this gets even uglier:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    description, 
    JSON_QUERY('[' + STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ',"' + STRING_ESCAPE(contacts, 'json') + '"'
            FROM Table1 T2 
            WHERE T2.id = T1.id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') 
    + ']') AS "members.contacts",
    [type] AS "type"
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE id = 'AA'
GROUP BY id, description, [type]
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Now we need to take both XML and JSON escaping into consideration, fun. This query assumes `id` is sufficiently unique to join on, which happens to be the case for this particular table.

Comment: I am getting this error: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name. And it looks like I will need SQL version 14 or higher. My version is 13.0.5102.14 :( . Is there any other function I can use instead of STRING_AGG ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `FOR XML PATH('')` to concatenate strings in SQL Server 2016. But rewriting the query to use this is not trivial because it needs a self-join, and we appear to have no primary key here (do you have one?) It's annoying enough that you should really consider upgrading to SQL Server 2017+ -- 2016 is not even supported anymore.

Comment: @MonirMonir: see my update. With queries like these it starts to become interesting to read your data structures with something like Dapper instead, and then serialize them the usual way client-side.

Comment: I wish I could upgrade easily. Lots of restriction from many system. Thank you so much for your help. Its almost working but where do I put "member"?

Comment: See update. That's just a question of renaming the column just like in the previous query, a simple oversight on my part.

Comment: I tried that before replied and I am getting output like this:  "members.contacts":["12", "23", "13", "45", "23", "43"] but I need output like this: "members": {
        "contacts": ["12", "23", "13", "45", "23", "43"]
    },

Comment: It [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cb08c0e5d61d1096a93fb10846c0a73e). Check if something's going on on the client side when representing that JSON.

Comment: Oh hang on, there's something weird -- I'm using single-quoted strings for the column aliases, which is wrong, but somehow dbfiddle doesn't mind. Nevertheless, that's not what we should do. Adjusting.

Comment: Ok it worked not. I was using FOR JSON AUTO but you wrote FOR JSON PATH. Its working now. You just saved my days man. I really appreciate your help.